# How can I POST data to JSON based REST API using NSJSONSerialization class?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsjsonserialization

I would like to see some concrete example(s)/tutorial on how to GET and POST data to and from a URL using NSJSONSerialization class.

I know how to actually GET the data , it is the POST which is confusing to some degree. Any helpful pointers will be much appreciated..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't use the `NSJSONSerialization` class for posting data. You use the `NSURL*` API (`NSURL`, `NSURLConnection`, `NSURLRequest`, etc.) instead.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/foo.php"];
NSMutableURLRequest *rq = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[rq setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSData *jsonData = [@"{ \"foo\": 1337 }" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[rq setHTTPBody:jsonData];

[rq setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[rq setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:rq completion:^(NSURLResponse *rsp, NSData *data, NSError *err) {
    NSLog(@"POST sent!");
}];
```

Comment: This does not compile for me on XCode 5? Also, how do you serialize objects?

Comment: @aledalgrande Xcode is not a compiler. (And unless you post specific compiler errors, there's no hope I can help you.) What do you mean by "serializing objects"? Serializing generic, custom objects is not trivial, you could get away with implementing the `NSCoding` protocol, but you may need something more complex -- again, based on the specific use case.

Comment: So is there no generic way in Objective C of serializing an object to JSON like there is in Java or Ruby? Do you have to resort to these hardcoded strings?

Comment: @aledalgrande If your objects are property list types (i. e. ones that are trivial to serialize: numbers, strings, dates, Booleans, and arrays and dictionaries of them), then you can serialize them to plists or JSON. Not otherwise.